# Collectd error "Dispatching value to all write plugins failed with status -1"

Tags: collectd

On my collectd server, the syslog file is filled very fast with many messages like these :

```
collectd-srv01.mydomain.com collectd[]: uc_update: Value too old: name = another_server.mydomain.com/some_metric; value time = 1674488856.852; last cache update = 1674488859.624;
collectd-srv01.mydomain.com collectd[]: Filter subsystem: Built-in target `write': Dispatching value to all write plugins failed with status -1.
collectd-srv01.mydomain.com collectd[]: Filter subsystem: Built-in target `write': Some write plugin is back to normal operation. `write' succeeded.
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution : the issue was not coming from the collectd server itself, but from several hosts sending data to it ( `another_server.mydomain.com` in the logs above )

2 different instances of collectd were running at the same time, which was obviously wrong. Killing one of the process removed the issue.